# Cloudwatch showing CPU Utilization higher than 100

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

1) Can somebody please explain me the number on Y Axis in the below graph ?
[image]

2) It's showing such high values as 170 on the axis but when I hover on the blue region separately, it shows me values( even on the datapoints) around 70-80. Is it showing me the average CPU Utilization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are CPU utilization, then most likely in Statistics, Sum has been selected meaning that:

> All the values submitted for the matching metric are added together

Change it to Average, or Maximum to plot a more meaningful graph. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html).

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi for the quick response. Quite helpful!